# jQuery request to WCF service ends with parsererror (Error: jQuery1101030437586596235633_1390485791492 was not called)

Tags: jquery, json, wcf, parse-error

I have a problem with calling a simple method in WCF service. I am stuck and I do not know how to solve this problem. I will appreciate any help.

**My WCF service:**

```
[ServiceContract]
interface IMyService
{
    [OperationContract]
    string GetSomething();
}

[ServiceBehavior(InstanceContextMode = InstanceContextMode.Single)]
class MyService : IMyService
{
    [WebInvoke(Method = "GET", 
               RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, 
               ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, 
               UriTemplate = "GetSomething", 
               BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Bare)]
    public string GetSomething() 
    {
        return "Hello";
    } 

}
```

Starting the service:

```
            using (ServiceHost host = new ServiceHost(typeof(MyService)))
        {
            host.Open(); // end point specified in app config

            Console.WriteLine("Hit Enter to quit.");
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
```

App.Config file

```
<configuration>
  <system.serviceModel>
    <behaviors>
      <endpointBehaviors>
        <behavior name="webHttp">
          <webHttp />
        </behavior>
      </endpointBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
    <bindings>
      <webHttpBinding>
        <binding name="webHttpBinding" crossDomainScriptAccessEnabled="true"/> 
      </webHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
    <services>
      <service name="testWCF.MyService">
        <endpoint address="http://localhost:8003/myservice"
          binding="webHttpBinding"
          contract="testWCF.IMyService"
          behaviorConfiguration="webHttp"/>
      </service>
    </services>
  </system.serviceModel>
</configuration>
```

Thats all about WCF service. My web application is running on `http://127.0.0.1:8085` and here is how I am sending jQuery request from web application:

```
$.ajax({
    url: "http://127.0.0.1:8003/myservice/GetSomething?callback=?",
    dataType: 'jsonp',
    cache: false,
    beforeSend: function () {
        console.log("Loading");
    },

    error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        console.log(jqXHR);
        console.log(textStatus);
        console.log(errorThrown);
    },

    success: function (data) {
        console.log('Success');
        console.log(data);
    },

    complete: function () {
        console.log('Finished all tasks');
    }
});
```

My response is following:
I can see in my JavaScript concole of my chrome, that response has been send from WCF service (content of GetSomething method is "Hello"), but I am getting following console output:

```
Loading
GetSomething:-1Resource interpreted as Script but transferred with MIME type application/json.
Object
parsererror
Error: jQuery1101030437586596235633_1390485791492 was not called
```

My succes function has never been executed. As I followed some of posts similar to this I undestood that it have something to do with Content-Type, but I could not find way how to get this work. Can anybody help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have resolved it by myself. Problem was, in App.config file. i have added `bindingConfiguration="webHttpBinding"`

Now my App.config file is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
  <system.serviceModel>
    <behaviors>
      <endpointBehaviors>
        <behavior name="webHttp">
          <webHttp />
        </behavior>
      </endpointBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
    <bindings>
      <webHttpBinding>
        <binding name="webHttpBinding" crossDomainScriptAccessEnabled="true"/> 
      </webHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
    <services>
      <service name="testWCF.MyService">
        <endpoint address="http://localhost:8003/myservice"
          binding="webHttpBinding"
          bindingConfiguration="webHttpBinding"
          contract="testWCF.IMyService"
          behaviorConfiguration="webHttp"/>
      </service>
    </services>
  </system.serviceModel>
</configuration>
```